# Get appname from user-agent

Tags: python, user-agent

I have strings like

```
VK/28 CFNetwork/711.4.6 Darwin/14.0.0
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13C75 Safari/601.1
Instagram 8.2.0 (iPhone4,1; iPhone OS 8_4; ru_RU; ru; scale=2.00; 640x960)    AppleWebKit/420+
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13C75 Safari/601.1
```

I want to know what is application were used to every string. It's

```
vk
mozilla
instagram
mozilla
```

I find the way to determine browser, but how get app I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get like this:

```
>>> log = '''VK/28 CFNetwork/711.4.6 Darwin/14.0.0
... Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13C75 Safari/601.1
... Instagram 8.2.0 (iPhone4,1; iPhone OS 8_4; ru_RU; ru; scale=2.00; 640x960)    AppleWebKit/420+
... Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13C75 Safari/601.1
... '''
>>> agents = [line.split()[0].split('/')[0] for line in log.splitlines()]
>>> print '\n'.join(agents)
VK
Mozilla
Instagram
Mozilla
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite clear if you are just trying to parse headers, or trying to match User-agent string against known apps/services that access you server. Since the former question is answered by Adem, here is explanation for the latter.

There's no way to find out the exact name of the app accessing your server through User-agent header. Although [HTTP/1.1 Standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.5.3) does specify User-agent string format, it's mainly used by human-operated browsers, while bots and other software may use simplified format or even spoof it (See [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent)).

So in your case it's better to come up with a list of apps you would like to track, then find their User-agent headers on the web (like [this](https://gist.github.com/Paratron/8676518) or [this](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Browserlist/)), so that you can parse your HTTP headers and match User-agent strings against the items in your list.